RDD lookup operation performing weirdly
I'm currently exploring PySpark and attempting to implement Dijkstra's algorithm using it. However, my query doesn't pertain to the algorithm itself; it's regarding the unexpected behavior of the lookup operation in PySpark. To aid in understanding what's happening, I've added print statements and comments throughout the code. This issue seems to be independent of Dijkstra's algorithm, so even if you're not familiar with it, your insights could still be valuable.
Here is my code:
def dijkstra(graph_dict, source_node):
    sc = spark.sparkContext
    
    # Initialize distances with infinity for all nodes
    distances = sc.parallelize([(node, float('inf')) for node in graph_dict])
    
    # Set the distance of the source node to 0
    distances = distances.map(lambda x: (x[0], 0) if x[0] == source_node else x)
    
    print(distances.collectAsMap())
    
    # Initialize priority queue with source node and distance 0
    pq = sc.parallelize([(0, source_node)])

    while not pq.isEmpty():
        # Get the node with minimum distance from the priority queue
        current_distance, current_node = pq.min()
        print(f'Current Node: {current_node}; Current Distance: {current_distance}')
        
        # Remove the current node from the priority queue
        pq = pq.filter(lambda x: x != (current_distance, current_node))

        # Iterate over neighbors of the current node
        for neighbour, weight in graph_dict[current_node].items():
            print(f'neighbour: {neighbour}; weight: {weight}')
            
            # Calculate the distance to the neighbor through the current node
            distance = current_distance + weight
            print(f'Distance: {distance}')
            
            # Lookup the current distance to the neighbor
            lookup_result = distances.lookup(neighbour)[0]
            print(f'lookup result for neighbour {neighbour}: {lookup_result}')
            
            # If the new distance is smaller, update the distance and add to priority queue
            if distance < lookup_result:
                print('True')
                distances = distances.map(lambda x: (x[0], distance) if x[0] == neighbour else x)
                pq = pq.union(sc.parallelize([(distance, neighbour)]))

    return distances.collectAsMap()

The input graph_dict is a python dictionary looks like this:
{'0': {'1': 7, '2': 1, '3': 4},
 '1': {'0': 7, '2': 1, '3': 1},
 '2': {'0': 1, '1': 1, '3': 10},
 '3': {'0': 4, '1': 1, '2': 10}}

Function is called as:
dijkstra(graph_dict, '0')

And this is the output (logs), I am getting when running it:
{'0': 0, '1': inf, '2': inf, '3': inf}
Current Node: 0; Current Distance: 0
neighbour: 1; weight: 7
Distance: 7
lookup result for neighbour 1: inf
True
neighbour: 2; weight: 1
Distance: 1
lookup result for neighbour 2: 1
neighbour: 3; weight: 4
Distance: 4
lookup result for neighbour 3: 4
Current Node: 1; Current Distance: 7
neighbour: 0; weight: 7
Distance: 14
lookup result for neighbour 0: 14
neighbour: 2; weight: 1
Distance: 8
lookup result for neighbour 2: 8
neighbour: 3; weight: 1
Distance: 8
lookup result for neighbour 3: 8
{'0': 0, '1': inf, '2': inf, '3': 8}

From the output, whats weird, is that the lookup result for neighbour 2 should be 'inf' and not 1 and same for all other neighbours. Only for the first time, that is for neighbour 1, its correct as 'inf'.
